# How to remove double quote characters from a String?

Tags: java, replaceall

My server json result is `"abcde"` (it contains `"`).

How to remove `"`?
This is not working.

```
 System.out.print(result.replaceAll("\"\",""));
```

Comment: `replaceaAll()` will replace *all* the groups that match this pattern so just use `replaceAll("\"","")`

Comment: Since your server returns JSON, why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: System.out.print(result.replaceAll("\"\","")); remove the second \. The line should be System.out.print(result.replaceAll("\"",""));

Comment: You do know that the `"` indicated that the `String` is a `String`?

Comment: Can you post the output of the methods you are trying? Did you try the one I mentioned `replaceAll("\\\"","")`? Might be that you are assuming `"` is present, whereas, it is not actually there, since some IDEs might show you the Strings that way. It's just an assumption based on your responses.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use [`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) since it accepts a regular expression as first argument (which you don't need it), use [`replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead:

```
System.out.print(result.replace("\"",""));
```

Comment: my server response result String    "aaaaaa"  
and i compare String to "aaaaaa"
but its not compare and show result  false .

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
System.out.println(result.replace("\"",""));
```

Comment: my server response :
"Please type in your Password!"

Comment: And i check 
if(result.equald("\"Please type in your Password!\""));
Resul show me false .

Comment: You replace your string with something else and compare them with (")  :) aaaa.equald(""aaaa"") ? It will always show you false :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`System.out.print("abcde".replaceAll("\"",""));`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the other solutions do not work, but just for the sake of being thorough, can you check with `replaceAll("\\\"",""));`

Since `replaceAll` method expects a regular expression!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the other answers don't work for you, you could always remove the `"` manually. By removing the first character and the last one.

```
String str = "\"abdc\"";
str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
```

It a bit of a hack, not sure if has the same efficiency of replace.

Comment: `String str = ""abdc"";` itself is wrong and should be `String str = "\"abdc\"";`

Comment: @VaibhavSolanki A little more specific?